# How to handle space in projection list value of RSQL

Tags: java, rest, filtering

I have a scenario where I need filter data using `RSQL`.
I need to get specific columns hence using `$projection=field_list=in=(FAMILY Id)` But as the column here "FAMILY Id" has a space , its throwing below error.

```
cz.jirutka.rsql.parser.ParseException: Encountered " <UNRESERVED_STR> "Id "" at line 1, column 23.
```

Was expecting one of:

```
<OR> ...
")" ...
```

If I pass the same in single quotes it would work , like `$projection=field_list=in=('FAMILY Id')`, but is there any other way to handle the same , as i have few more scenarios in the similar way where putting the same in single quotes too does not work.

Thank you.

~Shyam

Answer (score 2):

It’s clearly stated in the [documentation](https://github.com/jirutka/rsql-parser#grammar-and-semantic):

> Argument can be a single value, or multiple values in parenthesis
>   separated by comma. Value that doesn’t contain any reserved character
>   or a white space can be unquoted, other arguments must be enclosed in
>   single or double quotes.

`field_list=in=(FAMILY Id)` is invalid, so you must use single *or* double quotes. There’s no any other way, I believe that quoting is sufficient for all the cases. Well, except you have both single and double quotes inside an argument – RSQL currently doesn’t specify any escape character.